# dplyr get final value using $ in a chain e.g. mtcars %>% select(mpg)$mpg

Tags: r, dplyr

```
mtcars %>% select(mpg) %>% class()
[1] "data.frame"
```

Is not the same as:

```
x <- mtcars %>% select(mpg)
x$mpg %>% class
[1] "numeric"
```

I have a dplyr chain with several operations. In the end I need the actual content of df$feature, not a data frame with one feature.

Doesn't work:

```
 mtcars %>% select(mpg)$mpg
Error in .$select(mpg) : 3 arguments passed to '$' which requires 2
```

Is there a way to get the numeric vector mpg within a dplyr chain? So that I don't have to create a variable defined by the dplyr chain, then a new variable df$x like a above. Is it possible to do it in a oner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, `select` always returns a `data.frame` with the columns selected even if it is a single column. The `class` would be obviously `data.frame` if we  are not extracting the column.  Instead, we can use `pull` to extract the column as a `vector` and now the `class` would be the `class` of the column/vector

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
    pull(mpg) %>% 
    class
#[1] "numeric"
```

---

If we use the `select` approach, then the column can be extracted with `$` or `.[[`

```
mtcars %>% 
    select(mpg) %>%
    .$mpg
    #or 
    #.[["mpg"]]
```

The `.` represents the whole dataset

Or using `extract2` from `magrittr`

```
mtcars %>%
     select(mpg) %>% 
     magrittr::extract2('mpg')
```

Or other options include `unlist` or `flatten_dbl`

```
mtcars %>% 
    select(mpg) %>% 
    flatten_dbl
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to `pull`, you can use `unlist` to transform the selected column of your data.frame into a vector:

```r
mtcars %>% select(mpg) %>% unlist() %>% class

[1] "numeric"
```